# Create custom Java inject annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, singleton

for learning purpose I would like to create two custom Java annotations:

- @SingletonBean to transform a class into a Singleton
- @InjectBean to inject the singleton instance where it's needed.

That means that if I write:

```
@SingletonBean
public class Engine{ ... }

public class Car {
   @InjectBean Engine engine;
   ...
}
```

I would expect that, under the hood, this would be the exact equivalent:

```
public class Engine{
   private static Engine instance;
   public static Engine getInstance(){
      if(instance==null){
         instance = new Engine();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   ...
}


public class Car {
   Engine engine = Engine.getInstance();
   ...
}
```

How can I define the two annotations and the corresponding behaviours?

Comment: The [Java Tutorial on Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) is a pretty good place to start with for learning how to right annotations. The Spring source code would also be another place to look.

Comment: If you are using hk2 you can create your own injection annotations using a custom injection resolver.  See: https://javaee.github.io/hk2/custom-resolver-example.html